# Why do I get "open destfile" error while using quantmod package on a code that worked fine for days

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm using quantmod package to retrieve daily data for the SPY from yahoo.It works totally fine for a year.About two days ago I satrted to get an error.
On another computer I don't have the same problem.
What happened and how can I solve this issue?

```
spy<-getSymbols(("AA") , src = 'yahoo', from = '2007-01-01', auto.assign = T)

Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  cannot open destfile
'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\RtmpmsmSzr\fileee86e885d74',
reason 'No such file or directory'
```

My working directory is:

```
    getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop"
```

Comment: I restarted the computer and it works.Still, it will be nice to understand the cause and how to avoid it.

Comment: Same with me, restarted will be fine... http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-Fiddle-td4715855.html